# ASP Dotnet 5 Antiforgery Token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

In dotnet5 the RequestVerificationToken is generated automatically if the form tag is used with blank action attribute. example: `<form action="">`. if the form action attribute is not blank then RequestVerificationToken is not generated automatically example: `<form action="Endpoint URL">`. I want it to generate the RequestVerificationToken automatically for non blank action attribute without using `asp-antiforgery=true` or `@HTML.Antiforgery()` statements explicitly. is there any way to do it?

Comment: use [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] attribute on your api

Comment: I want the API to validate the AntiForgeryToken

Comment: then checkout this [article](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-core-antiforgery-token-jquery-ajax-post-405)

Comment: @Mahdi thanks. as per this I either have to use IAntiforgery Interface or generate the RequestVerificationtoken explicitly in the form. There is no other way.